# FirebaseException: Failed to bounce to type in Android but Model class properties and JSON properties are same

Tags: android, json, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm still getting an exception:

```
com.firebase.client.FirebaseException: Failed to bounce to type exception
```

for following line

```
Peoples people = dataSnapshot.getValue(Peoples.class);
```

**Peoples object**

```
public class Peoples {

    private String ambition;
    private String fname;
    private String lname;
    private String emailid;
     Peoples(){

     }
     Peoples(String ambition,String fname,String lname,String emailid){
        this.ambition=ambition;
        this.fname=fname;
        this.lname=lname;
        this.emailid=emailid;
     }


     public String getAmbition() {
        return ambition;
     }

     public String getFname() {
        return fname;
     }

     public String getLname() {
        return lname;
     }

     public String getEmailid() {
        return emailid;
     }
}
```

**Data**

```
peoples  
 -K3yJU5z646EZiIliPuJ
   ambition: "Doctor"
   emailid: "harshan@gmail.com"
   fname: "Mohammed"
   lname: "Thanish"
 -K3yJcoLNqY228wQO1AX
   ambition: "Doctor"
   emailid: "ndlhassan@gmail.com"
   fname: "Mohammed"
   lname: "Thanish"
```

**Code**

```
userRef
  .orderByChild("emailid")
  .equalTo("ndlhassan@gmail.com")
  .addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
      System.out.println("USERRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRR are " + dataSnapshot.getChildrenCount() + " blog posts");
      System.out.println("USERRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRR" + dataSnapshot.getValue());
      Peoples people = dataSnapshot.getValue(Peoples.class);
      System.out.println("USERRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRR" + people.getEmailid());
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(FirebaseError firebaseError) {

    }
  });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you're listening to a `value` event, the `onDataChange` method can potentially be called with multiple matching items. Even though in your case there is only one match, your code will need to be prepared to handle multiple:

```
public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
  System.out.println("There are " + dataSnapshot.getChildrenCount() + " children");
  for (DataSnapshot child: dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
      Peoples people = child.getValue(Peoples.class);
      System.out.println("Child: " + people.getEmailid());
  }
}
```

Alternatively, you can add a ChildEventListener. https://www.firebase.com/docs/android/guide/retrieving-data.html

Comment: Thank you very much Mr. Frank van Puffelen
I couldn't get how to write code to get single request